# Android : want to access to a textview in a viewholder in my mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

I am so sorry for my bad English, but here is my problem :

I use a  custom ListView  like ArrayAdapter and I create my ArrayAdapter as a intern class in my main Activity like that :

```
    /*This is my Main Activity*/
    public class  KhassaideActivity extends Activity {

    ViewHolder holder;
    KhassaideAdapterbi listadapter ;
    ListView l ; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      l= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listDieuzbou);
      listadapter = new KhassaideAdapterbi(this, R.layout.affichage_khassaide, rowItems);
      l.setAdapter(listadapter);
    }

    /*This is my intern class ArrayAdapter*/
    private class KhassaideAdapterbi  extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{

    Context context;
    public KhassaideAdapterbi(Context context, int resourceId,
            List<RowItem> items) {

        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView trad;
    TextView trans;
    TextView number;
}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

 holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.affichage_khassaide, null);

            holder.number = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            holder.trad = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.traduction);
            holder.trans = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.transcription);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.arabe);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        holder.trad.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.trans.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        holder.number.setText(rowItem.getNumber());
        return convertView;
    }



}
```

So in my main Activity I want to access and share the values of the two TextView when the user click on a menu item like that :

```
    case R.id.action_share:

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, listadapter.holder.trad.getText());
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

But I get a NullPointerException at this line **listadapter.holder.trad.getText()**

Is anyone have a solution for that? Thank you in advance. And sorry once again for this bad english

Comment: in your onCreate method at where you have call setContentView method?

Comment: I omitted in the above code but i call it at first in my method onCreate

Comment: like that `        @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_khassaide);`

Answer (score 2):

you should change this....

```
private class KhassaideAdapterbi  extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem>{

Context context;
List<RowItem> Rowitems;
public KhassaideAdapterbi(Context context, int resourceId,
        List<RowItem> items) {

    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.Rowitems = items;
}
```

now get data  from Rowitems ...

Comment: but the value Rowitems is not used finally or is it a attribute of my main activity?

Comment: thank very much it's work perfectly , i use the rowItems like an attribute in my mainactivity.